# String formatting in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have fields for street name, city, state and zipcode for User model, and I want to simply make a Google Map query with these values like

```
https://www.google.com/maps?q=your+query
```

so that I can open hyperlink it to the actual google map page. Now I am wondering how I can make these parameters into the format of your+query. I want to know if I can do it in the template or controller and how I can pass those variables.

Comment: Also, one more thing is I realize that I would need to make all the spaces into a + sign, and in which file should I put such a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CGI.escape` to URL-encode the query. Here are the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-escape).

`"https://www.google.com/maps?q=#{CGI.escape params[:query]}"`

Answer (score 3):

Ruby includes the [URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) module which is the preferred way of manipulating URIs as it's aware of encoding:

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('https://www.google.com/maps?q=your+query')
uri.query # => "q=your+query"

params = URI::decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h # => {"q"=>"your query"}
params['q'] = 'my query'
uri.query = URI::encode_www_form(params)

uri.to_s # => "https://www.google.com/maps?q=my+query"
```

Rails has a number of helpers for parsing and manipulating them though as that's what Rails is built around, so dig into your tutorial or book and take advantage of those.